# Is there way to find when self signed certificate will expire for Adobe Air application?

Tags: air, certificate

I have to release my Adobe Air application but the build process was "setup" by a different developer. (He made a self signed cert and wrote a batch file to call adt for packaging the application).

Adobe mentions that such self signed certificates are valid for 5 years.
Now I have no idea when that certificate will expire as I don't know when it was created.

Also will my installed application stop working on expiry or only new installations will fail ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `migrate` commandline switch for `adt`. If and when the certificate expires you can update your air application to use a new certificate. Read more about updating AIR 1.5 applications [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS13ACB483-1711-43c0-9049-0A7251630A7D.html). I also suggest you take a look at [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.1/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff2.html) page (this is about upgrading AIR 1.1 applications -- just in case you are not on 1.5).

Comment: @dirkgently
thanks for the reply, but i have successfully packaged the application using the cert, there is no "migration" issue per say.
I am just concerned that if client installs and re-installs in future we just dont know when new installation will start failing.

Comment: You can include an 'update' url in your application. Whenever your application is installed/user wants to update the application this links will be checked for updates. You can post a new certificate via an application update.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible way is to check the time stamp on the certificate file.
Only new installations will fail after 5 years.